# How to change UILabel text with user typing message

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

Is it possible to change the UILabel text by user interaction? Or is it necessary to do it with a UITextField element?

Can you tell me the way of doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UILabel` is inherently not editable, from the [class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/):

> The UILabel class implements a read-only text view.

You would have to use a `UITextField` or a `UITextView` - `UITextView` being more like a `UILabel` than a `UITextField`.

From the [UITextView class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextView_Class/index.html):

> The UITextView class implements the behavior for a scrollable, multiline text region. The class supports the display of text using custom style information and also supports text editing. You typically use a text view to display multiple lines of text, such as when displaying the body of a large text document.

Comment: Thanks for your response!! But is it possible to include a initial message (programmatically) and then let the user to change it? Is there any tutorial or web where I can check how to do it? Regards

Comment: Yeah, just set the text of the `UITextView` in your viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear.

Comment: No, but I mean the way to let the user change it by interaction with the textfield

Comment: You can set the initial text as I just said. The user will be able to edit it because as mentioned in my post `UITextView` supports editing. I suggest actually trying to do it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that it's possible to change the UILabel text by user interaction.

I would use a UITextField with no borders to make it look like a UILabel. You can do this using the Attributes Inspector in the storyboard.

[image]